# How to solve this MSBuild import problem?

Tags: msbuild

I have an API that imports many modules. Here's the code snippet:

```
<Import Project="/CRM/Ticketing/Module.targets" />
<Import Project="/CRM/Customers/Module.targets" />
<Import Project="/CRM/Loyalty/Module.targets" />
<Import Project="/CRM/Club/Module.targets" />
```

And each of those `Module.targets` files define two properties and import a base `Module.targets` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Project>CRM</Project>
    <Module>Customers</Module>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="/Base/Module.targets" />
```

Or

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Project>CRM</Project>
    <Module>Club</Module>
</PropertyGroup>

<Import Project="/Base/Module.targets" />
```

And this is the base `Module.targets`:

```
<Project>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="$(Project).$(Module).Models">
      <HintPath>/$(Project)/$(Module)/Packages/$(Project).$(Module).Models.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="$(Project).$(Module).DataAccess">
      <HintPath>/$(Project)/$(Module)/Packages/$(Project).$(Module).DataAccess.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="$(Project).$(Module).Business">
      <HintPath>/$(Project)/$(Module)/Packages/$(Project).$(Module).Business.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="/$(Project)/$(Module)/Database.json">
      <Link>Database\$(Module).json</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The problem is that MSBuild complains that:

> warning MSB4011: "/Base/Module.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "/CRM/Customers/Project.targets (8,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [/CRM/CustomerApi/Api.csproj]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Nots sure if this can be solved like this, it's also not really the 'msbuild way'; have you considered declaring the different Projects/Modules as Items instead then have the Reference batch i.e. loop over them?

Comment: How should I loop over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using so-called [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching), which is the msbuild way to loop over things.

A.proj:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Include="CRM">
      <Module>Ticketing</Module>
    </Projects>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

B.proj:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Include="CRM">
      <Module>Customers</Module>
    </Projects>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Final project:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Show">

  <Import Project="A.proj"/>
  <Import Project="B.proj"/>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Update="@(Projects)">
      <ReferenceName>%(Identity).%(Module).Models</ReferenceName>
      <ReferenceHintPath>/%(Identity)/%(Module)/Packages/%(Identity).%(Module).Models.dll</ReferenceHintPath>
    </Projects>
    <Reference Include="@(Projects->'%(ReferenceName)')">
      <HintPath>%(ReferenceHintPath)</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="Show">
    <Message Text="%(Reference.Identity) %(Reference.HintPath)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Output:

```
CRM.Ticketing.Models /CRM/Ticketing/Packages/CRM.Ticketing.Models.dll
CRM.Customers.Models /CRM/Customers/Packages/CRM.Customers.Models.dll
```

The first ItemGroup loops over Projects and adds the reference name and path to each, the second ItemGroup then adds the actual Reference.